# JQuery + Primefaces, not working

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Hy there,

i tries to use JQuery with Primefaces in my JSF View. My code looks like this.
But it doesen't work. No accordion is showing.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>MAKE_IT</title>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
</h:head>
<!-- Code begins here -->
<h:body>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget,
            quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida
            in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam
            mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a
            velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum
            sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris
            turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.
            Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, you need to call `.puiaccordion()` and not `.accordion()`.

Comment: no errors. .puiaccordion()? Why?